# Ubuntu Studio install still runs off external hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm new to linux and love it. I've been using Ubuntu Studio for around a month on "Try Ubuntu" I got it loaded without any hiccups.

Now I thought I installed it to internal HDD and split my internal HDD half for windows half for ubuntu.

When I start up my laptop without the external hard drive. I get 
GRUB prompt - boot from Windows, Ubuntu etc...

I tab to Ubuntu and press enter and it then tells me no boot bios?

thanks for any advice

```
 administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

john@john-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo fdisk -lu
[sudo] password for john: 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8B2504C2-6EE8-423F-9A24-FC246A673A53

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2      534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      567296 1910232541 1909665246 910.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1910233088 1911943167    1710080   835M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  1911943168 1953513471   41570304  19.8G Microsoft basic data




Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204138496 bytes, 1953523708 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 45FE8261-149C-4993-92F7-BFC7B2FFC8EC

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048  987379825 987377778 470.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2   987381760  988430335   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb3   988430336 1937068031 948637696 452.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  1937068032 1953521663  16453632   7.9G Linux swap
john@john-HP-Notebook:~$
```

I plug the external hard drive in and theres no problems.

I also wish to delete windows for ever and have my files already backed up to another external HDD.

Comment: Just change the boot order back to Windows bootloader at UEFI and Windows will boot directly as it should and as it did before, without the Ubuntu USB. Then you can, from Windows, make room for a dual boot if you want, by shrinking Windows partitions.

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your answer. I cleaned the external hdd reloaded ubuntu iso then reinstalled and just wiped out windows from the install menu. working fully now with ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `/dev/sda` is used entirely by Windows and your `/dev/sdb` is split roughly 50/50 between Windows and Ubuntu. Given your description, I suspect that `/dev/sdb` is your external disk, but I can't be 100% positive of that.

If I'm right, then the problem is that GRUB (the Ubuntu boot loader) is installed partly on `/dev/sda1` (the EFI System Partition, or ESP, on that disk) and partly on `/dev/sdb3` (the main Linux partition), with GRUB set as the default boot program. This works fine when the ESP and Linux partition are on the same disk, or even on two different, but permanently-installed, disks; but when you unplug the Linux disk, this approach falls to pieces. There are several solutions to this problem, such as:

- Live with it. You can type `exit` (IIRC; or maybe it's `quit` or something similar) at the `grub>` prompt when you try to boot with the external disk unplugged and the system will probably boot to Windows.
- Shrink a partition on `/dev/sda` to clear up about 500-1000 MB of space, create a new Linux partition there, and set it up as a separate `/boot` partition. This will require copying kernels from the current `/boot` files to the new partition; modifying `/etc/fstab` to permanently mount the new partition at `/boot`; and re-installing GRUB, or at least doing some heavy-duty reconfiguration of it. Still, this may be easier than doing a full re-installation of Ubuntu, particularly if you've invested time in configuring Ubuntu or have files you want to preserve.
- Install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to the ESP on `/dev/sda`. rEFInd does not rely on any Ubuntu files once installed, so when you boot with the external disk unplugged, rEFInd installed on `/dev/sda` will detect just Windows (and GRUB, but you could delete or hide that); and with the external disk plugged in, rEFInd will detect both Windows and Ubuntu. If you install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package, it will install to whatever ESP is mounted at `/boot/efi`; type `df /boot/efi` to find out what that is. Chances are it's `/dev/sda1`, which is what you'd want.
- Re-install Ubuntu, but put it entirely on `/dev/sda`, as MichaelBay suggests. If this is what you intended originally, it might be worth doing, despite the extra hassle. OTOH, it *is* extra hassle. You'll probably also want or need to reclaim the space used by your current Ubuntu installation.

Comment: thankyou for your answer, opted for your last reccomendation and wiped out windows for good!! I am now running fulltime on ubuntu studio ....now just tweaking it..